How to handle text and number features with pytorch?
My dataset contains some numeric columns and one text column. Text is a one sentense.
I want to use this dataset for classification using pytorch. But don't know how to handle text column.
Previously i used Catboost with text_features option and it's works fine. Also i tried turn text into embeddings and use it like any other numeric feature in Catboost and it also works fine. Here is what i did:
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("DeepPavlov/rubert-base-cased", num_labels = 3, output_attentions = False, output_hidden_states = False)

def getEmbedding(text):
    
    encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', truncation=True,
                                          max_length=max_len, add_special_tokens=True)
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        output = model(**encoded_input)
        output = output[1].detach().cpu().numpy()[0]
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    
    return output

data['embedding'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: getEmbedding(x))
data= pd.concat([data, data['embedding'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

But now i'm curious what i use pytorch model with Bert layer for the text and after concat result with numeric features and pass it into Linear layer. Something like:
class BaselineNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden1, out_size, drop1):
        super(BaselineNN, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') # bert layer for text feature
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden1) # linear layer for numeric features
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(???, out_size) # output layer
    
    def forward(self, input1, input2, mask, token_type_ids):
        _, output_1= self.l1(input1, attention_mask = mask, token_type_ids = token_type_ids)
        output_2 = self.fc2(input2)
        combined = torch.cat((output_1.view(output_1.size(0), -1),
                          output_2.view(output_2.size(0), -1)), dim=1)
        out= self.fc2(combined)
        return out
    
    def init_weights(self, m):
        if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniformal_(m.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='relu')
            m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

Is it even worth? I mean i can trun text into embeddings and embddings into numbers and use it in model.
And if it worth - How can i correctly concat Bert output and linear layer output to pass it into next layer?
